# Do we need to normalize the eigen values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector

When using eig function in Matlab, it seems that this function has already normalize the values of the eigenvalues. Do we need to write some lines of code to normalize the eigenvalues after using the eig function.

Comment: What do you mean by normalizing eigenvalues? Did you mean eigenvectors instead?

Answer (score 3):

The function `eig` in MATLAB normalizes the eigenvectors (not the eigenvalues).

See the following from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html):

> [V,D] = eig(A) returns matrix V, whose columns are the right
>   eigenvectors of A such that A*V = V*D. The eigenvectors in V are
>   normalized so that the 2-norm of each is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors can vary by a scalar, so a computation algorithm has to choose a particular scaled value of an eigenvector to show you.  `eig` chooses 2-norm = 1.  Just look at the eigenvector definition to see why: AV=VD.  V shows up on both sides, so you can multiple V by anything without affecting the equation.

Eigenvalues do not vary.  Look again at AV=VD.  D is only on one side, so it can't be scaled.